# Django urls.py and optional parameters in def view

Tags: python, django, url, parameters

I've this in urls.py. I'm using paginator. If I get some UsuarioName it responses me the UsuarioName profile and page = 1. But I could see following pages. I've followed Django paginator doc.

```
url(r'^(?P<UsuarioName>.+)/$', "actividades.views.ShowUserPage"),
url(r'^(?P<UsuarioName>.+)/?(?P<page>.+)/?$', "actividades.views.ShowUserPage"),
```

views.py, If I write def.. (... UsuarioName, page), is wrong, because there's no parameter for the first url entry.

```
def ShowUserPage(request, UsuarioName, page):
    UsuarioModel = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=UsuarioName)
    UserPage = '<div class="userpage">'
    UserPage += '<strong>' + UsuarioModel.titulo + '</strong><br>'
    UserPage += UsuarioModel.user.get_username() + "<br>"
    UserPage += UsuarioModel.descripcion + "<br>"
    UserPage += '</div>'
    UserPage += '<strong>Actividades de usuario</strong>'
    UserActList = UserActivities.objects.filter(user=UsuarioModel).values('actividad','fecha_alta')
    paginator = Paginator(UserActList, 2)
    page = 1
    try:
        ActPage = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        ActPage = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        ActPage = paginator.page(1)
    #print ActPage.object_list[0]['actividad']
    for ActividadActual in ActPage:
        UserAct = Actividad.objects.get(id_evento=ActividadActual['actividad'])
        UserPage += '<div class="activity">'
        UserPage += '<strong>Actividad: ' + UserAct.titulo + '</strong><br>'
        UserPage += 'Fecha actividad: ' + UserAct.fecha.strftime("%d-%m-%y") + '<br>'
        UserPage += 'Fecha alta: ' + ActividadActual['fecha_alta'].strftime("%d-%m-%y") + '<br>'
        UserPage += '</div>'
    return HttpResponse(UserPage)
```

How can I solve it? I know that I can split url path, but I don't like it too much..

Comment: The question is not quite clear.
Do you not want to see ?page=1 in the url and still be able to render the response as per the page demanded in the url?

Comment: I want to render the response if I have page argument or if not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do this :

```
url(r'^(?P<UsuarioName>.+)/(?P<page>\d+)/?$', "actividades.views.ShowUserPage"),
url(r'^(?P<UsuarioName>.+)/$', "actividades.views.ShowUserPage"),
```

I changed the order of the urls, so that /me/3 wouldn't be matched first by (?P.+). I've also set a number type to the page argument, because it will always be a number, so there is no reason to catch anything else than than.

And then, you should try :

```
def ShowUserPage(request, UsuarioName, page=1):
```

It should allow the query without a page to call this function without a page argument (defaulting it to 1).

I didn't try any of this, so if it doesn't help, I'll take a deeper look into it.

Comment: yep, the problem is that ShowUserPage sometimes have page argument and others no, but I can't set page=1 as default because I won't be able to catch it.

Comment: What won't you able to catch? About the question about POST in the next answer, you could do it by post, but it won't show in the url, and you'll have to create forms for that, instead of simple links. Not sure it's the easiest path...

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

Default page = 1. Always,
next time, there will be a link for getting following pages. I can get it as a POST argument?¿?¿?